# Awk storing data into array in bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to read a file in a Bash script. But I want to skip some lines - for example the first two lines. The lines should be stored in an array.

How can I do that?

I have tried `awk '2,$ p' $1`, but it is stored in one string, not in an array.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want something simpler like `tail -n +3`

Comment: String is a char array.

Comment: `awk '2,$ p' $1` seems like should be `sed -n '2,$ p' $1`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use *read* instead of *awk*?

You can use something similar to the following:

```
while read b; do
  array[i] = $b
done < input.file.txt
```